# How can I send textarea to another page and have it stay there, as well as send to my database?

Tags: php, forms, post

So I used the code:

```
<form id="content" name="content" action="profile.php" method="post">
    <p>Title:</p>
    <input type="text" name="title">
    <br />
    <p>Scare:</p>
    <textarea type="text" name="outputtext" style="width: 99%;" id="outputtext" placeholder="Scare Here..." cols="25" rows="10" type="text"></textarea>
    <br>
    <input type="submit">
    <input type="reset">
</form>
```

in order to actually post to the profile.php page, and on the profile page I put,

```
<?
    $file_contents = stripslashes($_POST['outputtext']);
?>
<textarea readonly rows="7 cols="9">
    <?PHP  print_r($file_contents); ?>
</textarea>
```

But how can I have the information entered in the post page to send to a database that is on PhpMyAdmin? And how can I make it stay there so that even if you navegate to a new page, such as going to make another post, the posts you've made stay on your profile?

Comment: PhpMyAdmin is not a db, its a db management script (one of many)

Comment: Really? it worked before sending information but then after awhile it just stopped. It works whenever a person wants to sign up, it sends their user_name, user_pass, and email to the table

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what it is you want to do. Are you wanting to update your database with the text from the textarea element without navigating to a new page? You will probably want to look into ajax as well as mysql, which is the database management system that phpmyadmin uses.

Comment: i want to be able to make a post in a <textarea> have that information send to my database, and show up on the profile page. similar to twitter, where you post something, it goes to their database, and it is posted on your page